# Dissallow robots for a while

Tags: wordpress, seo, search-engine-bots

I'm will be hosting a wordpress site on a live server. But it will be in test phase for while. How can I tell the robots not to index the site till then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stick a "disallow everything" robots.txt file in (with a relatively short [expires header](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/)) and edit it when you are ready for indexing.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`robots.txt`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard) to disallow, then allow whenever your site goes live.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using WordPress 3.x, you can go on the admin page to the `Settings` menu, then click `Privacy`.  There is an option there to block robots.

Answer (score 1):

Disable your RSS feed, too, as Google uses RSS for indexing. Use [WordPress › Absolute Privacy « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/absolute-privacy/) or use in functions.php:

```
function fb_disable_feed() {
    wp_die( __() );
}

add_action('do_feed', 'fb_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rdf', 'fb_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rss', 'fb_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rss2', 'fb_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_atom', 'fb_disable_feed', 1);
```